# Encoding and decoding byteValue, intValue, shortValue, hashCode, longValue

Tags: java, int, byte, decode, encode

How can I print back the original long value, after converting it to byteValue, intValue, shortValue, hashCode, longValue.

```
import java.lang.*;
public class IntegerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         Long l = 5148765430l;
         int t = l.intValue();
         System.out.println((new Integer(t)).byteValue());
         System.out.println((new Integer(t)).doubleValue());
         System.out.println((new Integer(t)).hashCode());
         System.out.println((new Integer(t)).longValue());
         System.out.println((new Integer(t)).shortValue());
         System.out.println((new Integer(t)).intValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't.  You threw away 32 bits of the value when you converted it to an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `long` occupies 64 bit, an `int` occupies 32 bit. When you covert a `long` to an `int`, the higher 32 bit will be abandoned, while the lower 32 bit will be saved as this `int`. For example:

```
Long sourceLong = Long.MAX_VALUE; // in binary 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
int i = sourceLong.intValue(); // in binary 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
System.out.println(i); // decimal -1
Long copyLong = Long.valueOf(i);
System.out.println(sourceLong.equals(copyLong));  //false
```

So, you can not convert this `int` back to the origin `long` since the higer 32 bit is lost.

One special case is when the orginal `long`'s higer 33 bit is all zero, it does not lose any accuracy even if the higer 32 bit is abandoned:

```
Long sourceLong = 1L; // in binary 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
int i = sourceLong.intValue(); // in binary 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
System.out.println(i); // decimal 1
Long copyLong = Long.valueOf(i);
System.out.println(sourceLong.equals(copyLong));  //true
```

---

The similar procedure happens when you convert an `int` to `short(16 bit)`, to `char(16 bit)`, to `byte(16 bit)`.